# Placing words inside existing brackets or end of filename

Tags: windows, batch-file, rename

I have this script that takes in a `directory tree` and renames files to include the words from every parent directory not yet existing in the filename.

It places the words at the end of the filename, inside brackets `[]`, for example, the file `R:\Done\Filed\The Title (2000) Creator [Rapid, Critical] xvp.dat` would be renamed to `The Title (2000) Creator [Rapid, Critical] xvp [Done, Filed].dat`

My script:

```batch-file
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

rem set input directory
set "inputDir=%1"
set "confirmation=false"

:process
for /r "%inputDir%" %%F in (*.*) do (
    rem use path as keywords
    set "words=%%~pF"
    rem replace \ with space
    set "words=!words:\=, !"
    rem remove non-keywords
    set "words=!words: The = !"
    set "words=!words: A = !"
    set "words=!words: An = !"
    
    rem remove word if exists in filename
    for %%W in (!words!) do echo %%~nF | find /i "%%W" >nul && set "words=!words: %%W = !"
    set "newName=%%~nxF"
    rem if all words already included do not rename
    if "!words:~1,-1!"=="" set "newName=%%~nF"
    rem if exist ] in filename, replace it with the words]
    echo !newName! | find "]" && set "newName=%newName:]=!words!]%"

    rem build the name
    echo !newName! | find "]" || set "newName=%%~nF [!words:~1,-1!]%%~xF"
    rem fix "] [" caused by multiple renamings, also causes fusion with non related bracketed datasets, which is fine
    set "newName=!newName:] [= !"
    rem fix trailing ", ]"
    set "newName=!newName:, ]=]"

    rem if name has changed either echo or rename when confirmed
    if not "%%~nF"=="newName" if /i not "%confirmation%"=="yes" echo old "%%F" & echo new "!newName!"
    if not "%%~nF"=="newName" if /i "%confirmation%"=="yes" rename "%%F" "!newName!"
)

rem if coming from second (confirmed) run then exit
if /i "%confirmation%"=="yes" exit /b
rem ask for confirmation to run again for real
set /p confirmation="confirm you want to perform all these rename tasks (yes/no)?: "
if /i "%confirmation%"=="yes" goto :process

endlocal
```

The new version should take, for example `R:\Done\Filed\The Title (2000) Creator [Rapid, Critical] xvp.dat`, or `R:\Done\The Title 2 (2002) Creator (Short, Critical) xvp.dat`, and rename them to `The Title (2000) Creator [Rapid, Critical, Done, Filed] xvp.dat`, and `The Title 2 (2002) Creator (short, critical) xvp [Done].dat`

with the replace `]` with `!words!]` command the `newName` for every file is `newName:m ]=]` so I wonder how to replace correctly here

Comment: Would you consider using PowerShell rather than a batch file?

Comment: @Compo Yea ok I need to delete this. Can you give me a tip though?

Comment: @Compo edited to show the invalid attempts